# After quitting out of a get.key function imputed text is invisible

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a cool scrolling animation for my text for a couple of projects and the code has been working fine.

However I wanted to add a way to skip the text printing whilst in the middle rather than having to change some settings. The way I am doing this is by having a separate thread watch for key presses then notifying the code to quickly print out the rest.

I have to use multithreading instead of threading because it allows me to force quit the check for a key press rather than it getting stuck there.

Now I have it almost working but I have run into an issue I have no idea how to solve. When typing in the input your text does not appear in the console (I use replit for coding). The input still works fine but you just can't see what your typing until you send it.

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Event
import random
import getkey
global stop_ping
stop_ping = Event()
random_char = [
    "፩", "፪", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "፫", "፬",
    "፭", "፮", "፯", "፰", "፱", "፲", "፳", "፴", "፵", "፶", "፷", "፸", "፹", "፺", "፻",
    "፼", "⑀", "⑁", "⑂", "⑃", "⑄"
]
settings = [0.1, False, True]


def slow_print_skip_thread():
    while not stop_ping.is_set():
        if len(getkey.getkey()) > 0 or stop_ping.is_set():  #looks for a key pres
            stop_ping.set()  #sends out a ping saying a key has been pressed
            return  #quits


def slow_print(message):
    global stop_ping
    stop_ping = Event()
    skip_thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=slow_print_skip_thread,
                                          args=())
    skip_thread.start()  #create's other threat to check for skips
    if settings[0] == 0:  #skips the epok animation if the delay is 0 :(
        for x in range(len(message)):
            print(message[x])
    else:  #makes the epok printing effect
        for z in range(len(message)):
            for x in range(len(message[z])):
                for y in range(5):
                    if stop_ping.is_set(
                    ):  #Checks for the ping to see if it is sent
                        break  #if the ping to stop is sent then it quits
                    else:
                        b = message[z][:x]
                        b += random_char[random.randint(
                            0,
                            len(random_char) -
                            1)]  #adds a random charicter for cool effect
                        print(b, end="\r")  #overwrites the previous message
                        time.sleep(settings[0] / 5)  #Waits
            print(
                message[z], end="\r\n"
            )  #fixes the ending so that it doesn't have the random charicter
    stop_ping.set()
    time.sleep(0.001)
    skip_thread.terminate()
    skip_thread = None


slow_print(["LONG MESAGE", "LONG MESAGE", "LONG MESAGE"])

input()
print(input())
slow_print(["Next test"])
print(input())
slow_print(["Next test"])
```

Please help.

Comment: I should point out that you are in fact using `multiprocessing` and not `multithreading`. these are very different and the former uses different processors and the latter uses different threads.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: `multiprocessing` lets the code utilise the PC processors (ie. 8, 16 cores etc). `multithreading` a single thread and shares the resources (better for i/o)...  finally, the modern way (since 3.7) is with `asyncio` which is like threading, but the user has more control....    you are doing `i/o`,  so `threading` or `asyncio` would be a correct approach.

Comment: A `multiprocessing` system has more than two processors whereas `Multithreading` is a program execution technique that allows a single process to have multiple code segments
`Multiprocessing` improves the reliability of the system while in the `multithreading` process, each thread runs parallel to each other.
`Multiprocessing` helps you to increase computing power whereas `multithreading` helps you create computing threads of a single process